# Don't cry for me

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix tells me when you cry.
>
> My suffix tells a story to my eye.
>
> Tell my infix, why be in despair?
>
> With my whole, I genuinely care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> HEART

*My prefix tells me when you cry.*

> HEAR, a cry can be recognized when heard, so crying can be recognized based on what you hear.

*My suffix tells a story to my eye.*

> ART, they say a picture speaks a thousand words.

*Tell my infix, why be in despair?*

> EAR when you speak to someone you speak to their ears.

*With my whole, I genuinely care.*

> HEART, the heart is the place where people say they feel compassion for another.